Can't switch Apple ID back
I switched my Apple ID to what was a temporary switch, or I intended. Now I can’t switch my Apple ID back to my original @icloud Apple ID. It says it’s an alias ID. But I can’t find it looking for aliases.
If I deactivate everything iCloud connects to on my iPhone 14 Plus (iOS 17.5.1) and try to change it back it simply says email address can’t be used at this time, something like that. I really need to change it back to my original @icloud Apple ID. How do I do this?
I’m trying to not to get back ups and things attached to the temporary Apple ID that’s currently my ID. But I’m running out of time I’ve got subscriptions that are past payment I don’t want to lose and just most of my life is attached to original @icloud ID that I want to switch back to. Can anyone please help me? I have no Mac computer access. I need to accomplish this on my iPhone 14 Plus. I’m on beta software as well that needs updated which that account is attached to my original @icloud Apple ID that I want to switch back to. I’ve had that Apple ID since the very first iPhone was released, so yes, it’s extremely important so much links back to that one. I have to switch back to @icloud Apple ID and not lose the info attached to it.

Please can you [edit] with exact steps you are following and exact error messages

I wouldn’t trust us to know what you did. I would get out paper and take notes and work with Apple support. You may be in a bind and unable to revert the changes, but they have the best shot at understanding what exactly you changed and where and when. You saying “you switched your Apple ID” isn’t clear since you can’t switch one account for another.

It's unclear from your post whether you've signed out of your original Apple ID or switched the email address of the account. However based on some words you've used I'm guessing you've changed the email address of one account.
If you set your Apple ID to a non-Apple email address, then you don't lose your original Apple ID email address. As you noted, it becomes an alias to the account when you go to sign in.
None of this prevents you from paying for subscriptions or accessing your data. You can continue to use the account. If you don't want the account attached to whatever email address you entered, then for the time being you can set up a new Gmail account and change it to that.
You may be able to remove the temporary email address you set as your Apple ID, but there's a possibility it's being restricted in this scenario. You'll have to contact Apple Support to confirm you're eligible to do that.

I’m fairly certain you can’t ever change back if you abandon one email as your primary Apple ID and that it’s forever burned. My strong advice is to not make “temporary” changes to emails without running your problem by Apple support to ensure you have a way back if that’s your plan.

Many account changes for an Apple ID are permanent, so please contact Apple directly if you have money invested in past purchase history, subscriptions and data with your AppleID.
The only time you want to change your primary Apple ID is a permanent and one way change in my experience. Even if you change your aliases within Apple, they generally will not let you go back. (Say you@mac.com,  you@icloud.com, and you@me.com - the change to the primary is permanent - you could choose to go to you@gmail.com but never back to a previous one.)
For anyone thinking this will fix a problem, my advice is to get on with Apple support and think of any way to accomplish your goal and not even assume you could promote a backup email to a primary Apple ID. Always get in writing from Apple if you want to change your primary to be sure you are good to go.
